# Which api/data structure does blender use to represent its meshes?

Tags: python, mesh, geometry

I am wondering which underlying data structure blender uses to represent its meshes. I tried going through the source code but answering that question myself is harder than expected.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for (at least in the broader sense) is the "bmesh module".
In the text editor, under "templates>python>Bmesh Simple", you can find a small sample on how to use it.

Comment: Tha may be it, will look it up